# Alexa Skill - doesn't seem to translate words into tokens

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My new Alexa skill works fine when I type a question at Amazon's service simulator.  But it fails when I talk to my Echo.

Is there some way to take a look at the data flow after the voice has been changed to written words, and before they are sent off to the end point?  I'd like to see what the Echo is doing.

I've put log stmts in my endpoint, and I can see requests coming in, but the requests that come in are wildly different from what I said.

Answer (score 0):

I found the immediate answer to my question.  I was saying for example:
Alexa, dreamhouse what is for sale

That fails.  But if I say this it works:
Alexa, ask dreamhouse what is for sale

Alexa likes that lead-in word.

The larger question, how do I intercept the intermediate results, after Alexa has tokenized the verbal input, is still unanswered.  But that may go unanswered for a long time, depending on Amazon's desires.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. The Alexa service goes from speech directly to your audio interaction model. It doesn't actually do text inbetween. A lot of people complain about this and ask for "the actual text spoken", but if they did things that way it would reduce quality.

So, no, there is no option to do that because it just doesn't make sense. Sorry.